# How to get elements of an associative array in the same order as it was entered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have an object in javascript (associative array) with numeric key and value and I pass through ajax to PHP and then go through it. The problem I have is that running the array in PHP is run by milking the keys numerically instead of showing in the same order that the data were entered.

**Javascript**

```
var object = new Object();

$("#example li").each(function(){
  key = $(this).attr("id"); //A number
  value = $(this).attr("value"); //Another number

  object[key] = value;
});

 // Pass the object by ajax to PHP

  ....
```

**PHP**

```
... // We retrieved the object in php

foreach ($object as $key => $value ) {
  echo $key;
  echo "-";
  echo $value;
  echo " / ";
}
```

Here is an example of the data entered in the object in javascriot and the order in which it appears after traversing it in php:

```
 Input data:   43->63 , 29->63, 33->63, 30->63, 44->63  (key->value)

 Output data:   29-63 / 30-63 / 33-63 / 43-63 / 44-63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy,

instead of using the numeric key as the array index, use a incremented index, and use another array as value. Like this:

```
var ix = 1;
$("#example li").each(function(){
  key = $(this).attr("id"); //A number
  value = $(this).attr("value"); //Another number
  object[ix++] = [key, value]; 
}
```

Then to retrieve the object in PHP:

```
foreach ($object as $row ) {
  echo $row[0];
  echo "-";
  echo $row[1];
  echo " / ";
}
```

if this still is out of other you can allways go back to old ways :)

```
for ($i = 1; $i< count($object); $i++ ) {
  echo $object[$i][[0];
  echo "-";
  echo $object[$i][1];
  echo " / ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @NelsonTeixeira, it works perfectly, I wanted to know another way to the traditional one you mentioned in the second part, but I did not know that I could do it that way.

Comment: This is good however I would pass `object[ix++]["key"] = key;` and `object[ix++]["val"] = value;` to use `$row["key"]` and `$row["val"]` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I would append the data to an array post the data like so:

```
var a = []; // post assoc
var b = []; // post numeric

$("#example li").each(function(){
  idv  = $(this).attr("id");
  val = $(this).attr("value");

  a.push({id: idv, value: val});
  b.push([idv, val]);
});

$.post('script.php',{assoc: a, numeric: b} );
```

And on the PHP side:

```
foreach($_POST['assoc'] as $arr){
  echo $arr['id'] . '->' . $arr['value'];
}

foreach($_POST['numeric'] as $arr){
  echo $arr[0] . '->' . $arr[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Xorifelse, that form was what I was going to try now with multidimensional Arrays, but I wanted to know how it would do with associative arrays. Although I have noticed that for this case it does not matter what you use.

Comment: Well if you want to use associative arrays, you could always push `{id: elm.attr("id"), value: elm.attr("value")}` and change the PHP accordingly with `echo $arr['id'] . '->' . $arr['value'];`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate you can pass the order as an array and loop that:

```
var object = new Object();
var order  = [];

$("#example li").each(function(){
  key = $(this).attr("id"); //A number
  value = $(this).attr("value"); //Another number

  object[key] = value;
  order.push(key);
});

 // Pass the object by ajax to PHP
```

Access the object with the value of the order array:

```
$object = $_POST['object'];

foreach($_POST['order'] as $key) {
  echo $object[$key];
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AbraCadaver, I had not thought of that.